# Error with form

Tags: php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
    if(!empty($_POST['cid']))
    {   
        mkdir('/home/something/public_html/test/ref/' . $cid . "_income" , 0777);
        copy('/home/something/public_html/test/ref/API.class.php','/home/something/public_html/test/ref/' . $cid . "_income" . '/API.class.php');
        if(isset($_POST['beach']
        {
        copy('/home/something/public_html/test/ref/beach/index.php' ,'/home/something/public_html/test/ref/'.$cid ."_income".'/index.php');
        copy('/home/something/public_html/test/ref/beach/beach.jpg' ,'/home/something/public_html/test/ref/' . $cid . "_income" . '/beach.jpg');
        copy('/home/something/public_html/test/ref/beach/video.png' ,'/home/something/public_html/test/ref/' . $cid . "_income" . '/video.png') ;
        }
        else if(isset($_POST['sunset']
        {
        copy('/home/something/public_html/test/ref/sunset/index.php' ,'/home/something/public_html/test/ref/'.$cid ."_income".'/index.php');
        copy('/home/something/public_html/test/ref/sunset/beach.jpg' ,'/home/something/public_html/test/ref/' . $cid . "_income" . '/beach.jpg');
        copy('/home/something/public_html/test/ref/sunset/video.png' ,'/home/something/public_html/test/ref/' . $cid . "_income" . '/video.png');
        }
        else if(isset($_POST['greenbg']
        {
        copy('/home/something/public_html/test/ref/green/index.php' ,'/home/something/public_html/test/ref/'.$cid ."_income".'/index.php');
        }
        else if(isset($_POST['orangebg']
        {
        copy('/home/something/public_html/test/ref/orange/index.php' ,'/home/something/public_html/test/ref/'.$cid ."_income".'/index.php');
        }
        else
        {
        copy('/home/something/public_html/test/ref/default/index.php' ,'/home/something/public_html/test/ref/'.$cid ."_income".'/index.php');
        copy('/home/something/public_html/test/ref/default/beach.jpg' ,'/home/something/public_html/test/ref/' . $cid . "_income" . '/beach.jpg');
        copy('/home/something/public_html/test/ref/default/video.png' ,'/home/something/public_html/test/ref/' . $cid . "_income" . '/video.png');
        }
    $_SESSION['click'] = $cid;
    $_SESSION['Active'] = $aid;
    $_SESSION['dropdown'] = $drop;
    }
    else
    {
    echo '<script language="javascript">';
    echo 'alert("Please “Enter your ID")';
    echo '</script>';
    }
}


?>
```

I'm facing problem , I'm using TextWrangler on MAC . I think something is wrong with the part of if and else if statement.

Those are themes selection by our client , so when they click the radio button . The value then passes into the PHP to generate a page reflecting on their choice.

Now i sense that the code that is messing with my function is this :

```
if(isset($_POST['beach']
        {
        copy('/home/something/public_html/test/ref/beach/index.php' ,'/home/something/public_html/test/ref/'.$cid ."_income".'/index.php');
        copy('/home/something/public_html/test/ref/beach/beach.jpg' ,'/home/something/public_html/test/ref/' . $cid . "_income" . '/beach.jpg');
        copy('/home/something/public_html/test/ref/beach/video.png' ,'/home/something/public_html/test/ref/' . $cid . "_income" . '/video.png')    ;
        }
        else if(isset($_POST['sunset']
        {
        copy('/home/something/public_html/test/ref/sunset/index.php' ,'/home/something/public_html/test/ref/'.$cid ."_income".'/index.php');
        copy('/home/something/public_html/test/ref/sunset/beach.jpg' ,'/home/something/public_html/test/ref/' . $cid . "_income" . '/beach.jpg');
        copy('/home/something/public_html/test/ref/sunset/video.png' ,'/home/something/public_html/test/ref/' . $cid . "_income" . '/video.png');
        }
        else if(isset($_POST['greenbg']
        {
        copy('/home/something/public_html/test/ref/green/index.php' ,'/home/something/public_html/test/ref/'.$cid ."_income".'/index.php');
        }
        else if(isset($_POST['orangebg']
        {
        copy('/home/something/public_html/test/ref/orange/index.php' ,'/home/something/public_html/test/ref/'.$cid ."_income".'/index.php');
        }
        else
        {
        copy('/home/something/public_html/test/ref/default/index.php' ,'/home/something/public_html/test/ref/'.$cid ."_income".'/index.php');
        copy('/home/something/public_html/test/ref/default/beach.jpg' ,'/home/something/public_html/test/ref/' . $cid . "_income" . '/beach.jpg');
        copy('/home/something/public_html/test/ref/default/video.png' ,'/home/something/public_html/test/ref/' . $cid . "_income" . '/video.png');
        }
```

I'm new to PHP , i hope I can learn something.

Comment: You are missing many closing parenthesis! And also, what error are you getting?

Comment: @MatteoTassinari , this is my error :

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in /home/something/public_html/default/step-2/index.php on line 24

Starting from the if isset beach first line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace all the lines like

```
if(isset($_POST['beach']
```

with

```
if(isset($_POST['beach'])) // see the closing parenthesis?
```

the final correct code would be

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
    if(!empty($_POST['cid']))
    {   
        mkdir('/home/something/public_html/test/ref/' . $cid . "_income" , 0777);
        copy('/home/something/public_html/test/ref/API.class.php','/home/something/public_html/test/ref/' . $cid . "_income" . '/API.class.php');
        if(isset($_POST['beach']))
        {
            copy('/home/something/public_html/test/ref/beach/index.php' ,'/home/something/public_html/test/ref/'.$cid ."_income".'/index.php');
            copy('/home/something/public_html/test/ref/beach/beach.jpg' ,'/home/something/public_html/test/ref/' . $cid . "_income" . '/beach.jpg');
            copy('/home/something/public_html/test/ref/beach/video.png' ,'/home/something/public_html/test/ref/' . $cid . "_income" . '/video.png') ;
        }
        else if(isset($_POST['sunset']))
        {
            copy('/home/something/public_html/test/ref/sunset/index.php' ,'/home/something/public_html/test/ref/'.$cid ."_income".'/index.php');
            copy('/home/something/public_html/test/ref/sunset/beach.jpg' ,'/home/something/public_html/test/ref/' . $cid . "_income" . '/beach.jpg');
            copy('/home/something/public_html/test/ref/sunset/video.png' ,'/home/something/public_html/test/ref/' . $cid . "_income" . '/video.png');
        }
        else if(isset($_POST['greenbg']))
        {
            copy('/home/something/public_html/test/ref/green/index.php' ,'/home/something/public_html/test/ref/'.$cid ."_income".'/index.php');
        }
        else if(isset($_POST['orangebg']))
        {
            copy('/home/something/public_html/test/ref/orange/index.php' ,'/home/something/public_html/test/ref/'.$cid ."_income".'/index.php');
        }
        else
        {
            copy('/home/something/public_html/test/ref/default/index.php' ,'/home/something/public_html/test/ref/'.$cid ."_income".'/index.php');
            copy('/home/something/public_html/test/ref/default/beach.jpg' ,'/home/something/public_html/test/ref/' . $cid . "_income" . '/beach.jpg');
            copy('/home/something/public_html/test/ref/default/video.png' ,'/home/something/public_html/test/ref/' . $cid . "_income" . '/video.png');
        }
        $_SESSION['click'] = $cid;
        $_SESSION['Active'] = $aid;
        $_SESSION['dropdown'] = $drop;
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'alert("Please “Enter your ID")';
        echo '</script>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Ouh , i forget about those >< my bad . I've been clingy without sleep .

Comment: Glad I could help :) If the answer helped you, feel free to upvote and/or accept it!

Answer (score 3):

You forgot the closing parenthesis after most lines starting with `if(isset(`. Add `))` to the end of the lines containing `if(isset(` and that don't already have closing parenthesis, so it looks like this: `if(isset($_POST['beach']))` or `else if(isset($_POST['orangebg']))`.

Comment: Thank you Pierre just a little error i missed out.